# Finding permutations and combinations possible to build a customizable bag

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

Working on producing a customizable bag and need to combine individual components to make full bag.

The bag following 4 components:

Body
Handle
Metal
Zip

Each bag has set of leathers or colored metal or colored cloth which can be used.

Example:

"Body" has the following leathers as applicable options...
Leather01, Leather02, Leather03, Leather04, Leather05

"Handle" has the following leathers as applicable options...
Leather01, Leather02, Leather03, Leather04, Leather05

"Metal" has the following colored metals as options...
Gold and Silver

"Zip" has the following colored cloth options...
Beige and Black

Considering the above, how do I get the permutations and combinations of making the bag.

Use cases:

A bag can built with the following:

body: Leather01
Handle: Leather01
Metal: Gold
Zip: Beige

Also, I am looking for half built bags as well, like...

body: Leather01

Or

body: Leather01
Zip: Beige

Looking for a way to calculate the possible combinations.

Comment: if you actually want all of the permutations the simple answer is "nested loops" if you just want to be able to calculate the permutations.... then there are M * N * O * P of them .... which looks on the surface like a big problem O(MNOP)... but since they aren't that numerous... (5*5*2*2) is all full built bags... now if you want combinations that are full built or all built you have (5*5*2*2) plus the half built (you will have to define that better before someone can give you numbers)

Comment: but if you want all partially build bags and fully built bags you can just add one to all of those number to be options + absent... (6*6*3*3)... of course that includes the non-bag option of 0,0,0,0